# Google Sheets IF OR statement

Tags: google-sheets

I've got a sheet where A1 is either blank, a number (12345), or a statement ("foo'). What I'd like to do is:

```
If A1 is blank then A2 is blank
 OR
If A1 is number then A2 = TODAY
 OR
IF A1 is "foo" then A2 = "bar"
```

I've got it started, and like the way this works, just need to add the "foo" part.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1), , TODAY())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using nested `IF` statements. Place the following in cell `A2`:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(A1), A1=""),"",IF(ISNUMBER(A1),TODAY(),IF(A1="foo","bar",ERROR.TYPE(A1))))
```

First, it checks if the cell is blank or a null string (if you don't want the null string part replace `OR(ISBLANK(A1), A1="")` with `ISBLANK(A1)`). If the cell is blank it makes `A2` equal to an empty string (note - an empty string is not the same as blank. To the best of my knowledge there is no way to return a "blank").

If the cell is not blank or a null string it then checks to see if it is a number. If it is a number it returns the current date.

If it is not a number it then checks to see if the cell is equal to the string "foo". If it is equal to foo it then returns the string "bar".

If none of those statements are true, it returns an error. You may replace `ERROR.TYPE(A1)` to any default action you want (perhaps simply `""`).

For example:

```
-----------------------
|          |          |
-----------------------
|         1| 4/27/2015|
-----------------------
|foo       |bar       |
-----------------------
|foobar    |   #N/A   |
-----------------------
```

Comment: Both solutions work! Although the error handling was not needed, I like the addition of handling should it be needed.

Answer (score 3):

You could rewrite this as:

```
IF (A1 is blank) THEN
    A2=""
ELSE
    IF (A1 is number) THEN
        A2 = TODAY
    ELSE
        IF (A1 is "foo") THEN
            A2 = "bar"
```

So in your spreadsheet, you can nest `IF` statements:

```
IF(ISBLANK(A1), "", IF(ISNUMBER(A1), TODAY(), IF(EQ(A1, "foo"), "bar", "ERR: A1 matched no pattern.")))
```